# Java - Merge data from 2 tables in different data source

Tags: java, python, mysql, sql, caching

I have a use case, where I have to merge data from 2 Tables (which are in different data sources).
Consider that each table has employee data (First name, last name, phoneNumber). For each employee, I will have to merge the phoneNumber data from both the Tables and other data will remain the same as in Table 1

1. If employee data is present in both Table 1 and Table 2, phoneNumber data will be merged as a comma separated values and other data will be sourced from Table 1
2. If employee is present only in Table 1, then entire data will be sourced from Table 1
3. If employee is present only in Table 2, then entire data will be sourced from Table 2

These Tables has about 40 lack rows of data each. Close to 5GB.
What is the best approach to do this in Java? My concern is if I pull the data from these 2 tables into Java cache, i will still have to loop thought the entire table 2 to see if an employee is present there as well.
Or will a python script be better?

Table 1

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM01 | Jhon | Doe | **12345** |
| EM02 | Dave | Joe | 34567 |

Table 2:

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM01 | Jhon | Doe | **89000** |
| EM03 | Gabe | Mai | 45678 |

Table 3 (After merging the phone numbers):

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EM01 | Jhon | Doe | **12345,89000** |
| EM02 | Dave | Joe | 34567 |
| EM03 | Gabe | Mai | 45678 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this as a SQL query.

Basically, you want a `full join`, but -- alas -- MySQL doesn't support that.

So, one method is:

```
select t1.EmployeeID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName
       concat_ws(',', t1.PhoneNumber, t2.PhoneNumber) as PhoneNumber
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
union all
select t2.EmployeeID, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName, t2.PhoneNumber
from table2 t2
     table1 t1 left join
     on t1.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
where t1.EmployeeID is null;
```

That is, get all the rows for the employees in `table1`.  Then add in the additional rows from `table2`.  For the first part, `concat_ws()` is convenient for combining the phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But in my case, the tables are in different Data sources. First one is there in SQL Server and the second table in Oracle Cloud server.

Comment: @codeguru Create linked server from one DBserver to another (for example, from SQL Server to OracleDB) then query like both tables are posessed on the same server.

Comment: @codeguru . . . Akina is correct.  Here is documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15.  Alternatively, export the Oracle table and re-import it in SQL Server -- assuming this is a one-time (or infrequent) operation.